# Get the number of records in the tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

It is possible to get the number of records that were entered in a treeview that for example come from a database. For example I want to do a kind of "Select query" and when inserting the data a message box will appear that tells me: "The number of "X" records was found"
Thank you!!!

[For example in this picture are inserted 9 records in each row, i need a way to obtain the records inserted in an integer number, in this case 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5qta.png)

Comment: Can't you just get the number from the raw results, or count them as you are inserting them?

Comment: In addition, what is a *record* in this context? It could be a whole line or just a particular cell in the `Treeview`. Its not clear what you are asking for.

Comment: In some cases there may be many records (more than 100) and counting them one by one is very complicated @BryanOakley

Comment: It takes python microseconds to return the length of a list, even if that list has tens of thousands of records. It will likely be orders of magnitude faster to count the records than to insert them into the treeview.